# Php spreadsheet generation

Tags: php, laravel, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to generate an excel spreadsheet with a DataValidation List column and it works fine with normal values but when I pass a value like "test (2)", it generates de excel but the List is empty. there is any way I can force the value as a string.

```
public function setColumnDropDown(int $column, array $values, $allowBlank = true, $showError = false, $lineStart = 2, $lines = 250)
    { 
        $objValidation = $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($column.$i)->getDataValidation();
        $objValidation->setType(PHPExcelValidation::TYPE_LIST);
        $objValidation->setErrorStyle(PHPExcelValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION);
        $objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
        $objValidation->setAllowBlank($allowBlank);
        $objValidation->setShowInputMessage(false);
        $objValidation->setShowErrorMessage($showError);
        $objValidation->setFormula1($values);     
    }
```

Comment: dont use `setFormula`. use `setCellValue`. https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/accessing-cells/

Comment: Why is this using `setFormula1` at the end? That makes really very little sense with a value such as `test (2)`, why is this not just `setCellValue` somewhere (if putting that value into a specific cell is what you actually want here)?

Comment: I'm trying to create a drop-down menu validation menu, so setcellvalue I think doesn't work. I'm using the getDataValidation() object